# Quickest way to eject a specific disk?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac

What is the Quickest way to eject a specific disk when I have multiple drives mounted? Right now I use spotlight to open Finder and manually search for the drive to unmount, is there an easier way to eject?

Comment: What do you mean with easier?

Comment: I just select the drive and do a COMMAND-E. Quick and easy.